# ValidationError: "expiresInMinutes" is not allowed NodeJs JsonWebToken

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am using NodeJs with JsonWebtoken Module.

I am facing this error when calling sign method of json web token

> ValidationError: "expiresInMinutes" is not allowed

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
    var user = {"Name":"Abdul"} //static data for test purpose.

    var token = jwt.sign(user, req.app.get('jwtTokenSecret'), {
          expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        // return the information including token as JSON
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });

}
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Ok I found that from https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

You have to call **expiresIn** rather than **expiresInMinutes**.

```
 var token = jwt.sign(user, req.app.get('jwtTokenSecret'), {
           expiresIn : 60*60*24
         });
```

Here the value of `expiresIn` is measured in seconds rather than minutes, so the value has to be put in properly.

Comment: var token = jwt.sign(user, req.app.get('jwtTokenSecret'), {
           expiresIn : 60*24; // expires in 24 hours 
         });

Comment: @MahmoudElgohary from the doc :  "expiresIn: expressed in seconds "

Comment: Please do not to what @MahmoudElgohary just suggested.  That would expire in 24 MINUTES, not hours.
For hours, use `{expiresIn : 'xh'}` where `x` is any number. example: `{expiresIn : '24h'}`

Comment: thanks man :+1: , next time i'll look at documentation first before stack overflowing :joy:

Answer (score 24):

`expiresInMinutes` was deprecated, you should use `expiresIn: '1440m'` for instance

Answer (score 8):

`expiresInMinutes` is deprecated, use `expiresIn` instead. From the [docs](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#usage) :

> `expiresIn`: expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span [rauchg/ms](https://github.com/zeit/ms). Eg: 60, "2 days", "10h", "7d"